# Conditionally define, during runtime, which of 3 classes will be used in the rest of C++ code

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, alias, typedef, using

Here is what I am trying to do in C++. From an external library that I use I have 3 classes, `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` that are identical in their public functions. I would like to decide, at the beginning of runtime, which one will be used by in the rest of my code depending on the hardware configuraion of the user.

To better illustrate what I mean, let me give an example that I know does not work. **If it were** possible to conditionally define a `typedef` at runtime, what I am trying to achieve **would** look as follows:

```
const int x = GetX(); //where GetX() is any function that calculates the value of x
typedef std::conditional<x > 0, MyClass1,
            std::conditional< x < 0, MyClass2,
                MyClass3>::type>::type TheClass;
```

So that in the rest of the code I would only refer to `TheClass`, in such a way that it does not matter whether it is aliasing `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` or `MyClass3`.

However, of course the code above does not work because when `x` has its value calculated from a function executed at the beginning of runtime, then `std::conditional` complains that `x` is not a constant. Which makes sense since `typedef` cannot be defined at runtime.

So, my question: is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do (not with `typedef` since I know it cannot be defined at runtime)? Remember that `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` are externally given by a library, and in such a way that I cannot easily alter them.

Comment: Not possible to have a `typedef` that is unknown until run time, as a `typedef` is a compile time concept.    Look up polymorphism.

Comment: @Peter Oh yes, I know that. I was actually trying to ask how could I achieve that idea *without* `typedef` precisely because of that. I updated the answer to better reflect it.

Comment: Do the three classes all inherit from a common base class?

Comment: @JonCage In the library they belong to, no they don't. But I guess that changing that so they inherit from an abstract, empty, class would be easy enough

Comment: Given that you have claimed they have the same interface, it would be easier to have the abstract base class provide that interface.   If you can change them so they inherit from an abstract empty base, you can also change them to inherit from an abstract polymorphic base (with virtual functions that each concrete class specialises as needed).   And the working of each derived class can interact with a class in the library if that can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this at compile time, the GetX function must be `constexpr`. 
Using the comparison operators also conflicts with the template syntax.  You will need to provide consexpr functions for less than and greater than:

```
constexpr int GetX(){ return 0;}
constexpr bool IsGreater(int x, int y) { return x > y;}
constexpr bool IsLess(int x, int y) { return x < y;}

typedef std::conditional<IsGreater(GetX(),0), MyClass1,
            std::conditional<IsLess(GetX(),0), MyClass2,
                MyClass3>::type>::type TheClass;
```

If you can't make `GetX()` constexpr (because the value is decided at runtime),
then you are looking for a [Sum Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).  They are quite common in functional programming languages and C++ now has library support in the form of [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Your example code could be turned into the following:

```
int main(){

  //a type that can be 1 of 3 other types
  std::variant<MyClass1,MyClass2,MyClass3> TheClass;

  //decide what type it should be at runtime.
  const int x = GetX();
  if      (x > 0) { TheClass = MyClass1(); }
  else if (x < 0) { TheClass = MyClass2(); }
  else            { TheClass = MyClass3(); }
}
```

Here, you are deciding the type at runtime.
You can go on to use pattern matching for evaluating what type is held.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I can't make `GetX()` constexpr since as I said, it's to be determined at runtime. Your second solution, however, seems to be the ideal case. Do you know which compilers already have such a C++17 feature? It seems that VS2015 still doesn't so I could not test it.

Comment: std::variant is pretty new.  Your best bet would be to pull in boost::variant.

Comment: I tried it with boost::variant. The problems with this solution are the following. First, `TheClass` here is not a class anymore, but a variable. For every variable to be created I would have to do the if-elseif-else and assign which MyClass is to be desired. This can be somewhat solved with a method. Second, acessing the variable becomes very cumbersome: `boost::get<MyClass2>(TheClass)`. Third, this way of accessing defeats the purpose, since I would have to know which type to look for (e.g. MyClass2 in the getter example I just gave) in advance, i.e. in compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can see is to use templates to generate the code for you. Modulo syntax errors, your `std::conditional` based solution does work provided you turn x into a compiler-known value. The trick is to wrap all of the code that uses the typedef in a template function/class that has the integer as a template parameter, as in:

```
template <int x>
void myMain(){
    using TheClass = typename std::conditional<x == 0, MyClass1, MyClass2>::type;
```

Then you want to make sure that you compile all of the variants (0 and non-zero in my example) and to do so you explicitly call both `myMain<0>()` and, say, `myMain<1>()`, as in:

```
if(x == 0){
    myMain<0>();
}
else{
    myMain<1>();
}
```

Now you've turned the condition into something that's evaluated at run-time, but you have the code for both cases compiled and you can execute each (or both) of them to your heart content.

This has the drawback of making whatever uses the class into a template or something that is called by a template. Beyond the "dispatching" point, I would advise to be template on the type rather than on the integer (see the function `doSomethingWithClass` in the example); this better expresses the fact that your code can work with all of the types you're going to instantiate it with. If you want to make sure that you can only instantiate the functions with the three classes you are interested in, you should consider using the CRTP pattern (curiously recurring template parameter).

On the other hand, this has the advantage (with respect to the other answer based on polymorphism) that you can use the stack rather than the heap.

You can find a working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a144d2c68a85ed3).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If all three inherit from a common class you can do this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual int GetSomething() = 0;
};

class Class1 : public BaseClass
{
    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Class2 : public BaseClass
{
    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

class TheClass : public BaseClass
{
    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return 3;
    }
};


BaseClass* classInterface;

const int x = GetX(); //where GetX() is any function that calculates the value of x
if (x > 0) { classInterface = new MyClass1(); }
elseif (x < 0) { classInterface = new MyClass2(); }
else { classInterface = new TheClass(); }

printf(classInterface->GetSometing());
```

If not, you'll need to wrap them and do something like this:

```
class Class1
{
    int GetSomething()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Class2
{
    int GetSomething()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

class TheClass
{
    int GetSomething()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

class BaseClass
{
    virtual int GetSomething() = 0;
};

class Class1Wrapper  : public BaseClass
{
    Class1 m_class;

    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return m_class.GetSomething();
    }
};

class Class2Wrapper : public BaseClass
{
    Class2 m_class;

    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return m_class.GetSomething();
    }
};

class TheClassWrapper : public BaseClass
{
    TheClass m_class;
    virtual int GetSomething() override
    {
        return m_class.GetSomething();
    }
};    

BaseClass* classInterface;

const int x = GetX(); //where GetX() is any function that calculates the value of x
if (x > 0) { classInterface = new MyClass1Wrapper(); }
elseif (x < 0) { classInterface = new MyClass2Wrapper(); }
else { classInterface = new TheClassWrapper(); }

printf(classInterface->GetSometing());
```

[Edit] ..if you want to save re-doing the if statements you could make a static method to generate a new baseclass:

```
static BaseClass* GetClass()
{
    BaseClass* classInterface;
    const int x = GetX(); //where GetX() is any function that calculates the value of x
    if (x > 0) { classInterface = new MyClass1Wrapper(); }
    elseif (x < 0) { classInterface = new MyClass2Wrapper; }
    else { classInterface = new TheClassWrapper; }
    return classInterface;
}
```

..then call it like this:

```
BaseClass* classInterface = GetClass();

// Do something

delete classInterface;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The only problem I see with this is that, since it is not actually substituting the three original classes by a new class-alias called `BaseClass` but using instances of `BaseClass`, then whenever I create a new instance of BaseClass, I will have to do the `if-elseif-else` check and assign a `new MyClassWraper` to the new instance. Is there a way to overcome that? I mean, to make all created instances of `BaseClass` to automatically check the value of `x` and then initialize themselves to the correct sub-class accordingly?